# Format Annotations on Bar chart to include comma separator and $ sign. Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, visualization

I am trying to format my annotation bars to include a comma separator and $. However I'm having trouble doing so. I am new to Matplotlib.

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

 
size = df['Size']
sales_dollars = df['$ Sales']
 
# Figure Size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize =(18, 10.5))
 
# Horizontal Bar Plot
ax.barh(size, sales_dollars)
 

# Add padding between axes and labels
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad = 10)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad = 10)
 
# Add x, y gridlines
ax.grid(b = True, color ='grey',
        linestyle ='-.', linewidth = 0.5,
        alpha = 0.2)
 
# Show top values
ax.invert_yaxis()
 
############### !Add annotation to bars! ##############
for i in ax.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_width()+0.2, i.get_y()+0.5,
             str(round((i.get_width()), 2)),
             fontsize = 14, fontweight ='bold',
             color ='grey')
        
# Add Plot Title
ax.set_title('US Multi Market Sales Dollars by Item Size',
             loc ='center', size = 15)

# Change size of tick labels
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)

# Axis Labels
ax.set_xlabel('Sales Dollars', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Size', fontsize = 15)


# Get rid of scientific notation
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))

# Show Plot
plt.show()
```

**Which produces the following:**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lines:

```
for i in ax.patches:
    plt.text(i.get_width()+0.2, i.get_y()+0.5,
             str(round((i.get_width()), 2)),
             fontsize = 14, fontweight ='bold',
             color ='grey')
```

Instead of passing the string itself, pass a formatted string:

```
'$ {:,}'.format(round((i.get_width()), 2))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, I knew there was some quick fix to this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any `float` `x` can be formatted to a `str` with the appropriate decimals using the f-string `f"{x:,}"`.